# wifi as wan and LAN

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

i do have an intel atom pc that runs debian 7. that pc has 3 ethernet ports (eth0,1,2) and a usb to wifi stick (wlan). i would like to connect as client to the wifi network 192.168.0.0/24, get an IP in the wifi from the range 192.168.0.0 and then eth0, 1,2 get IP from that subnet as well. If a PC connects to eth0,1,2 then to get an IP from the 192.168.0.0/24 network (over the wifi)

this is my current /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid "Com_SAT_PLUS"
wpa-psk "wh@t3v3r123"

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp


auto eth2
iface eth2 inet dhcp

auto eth2
iface eth2 inet dhcp
```

I can get connect to the wifi network ( i see in on the router) but there are no IP addresses on eth0,1,2 and the system is not able to ping anywhere even on the default gateway.

could someone help me please what else to do to fix that problem, please?

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to do that.
I suggest you to make a bridge between wlan0 with one of ethX.
So your ethx will be part of wlan network.

Follow this how-to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConnectionBridge

On my way, try this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bridge-utils
```

modify /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto brwlan
iface brwlan inet static
bridge_ports wlan0 eth0
bridge_fd 0
bridge_maxwait 0
bridge_stp off
address 192.168.0.X
network 192.168.0.0/24
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
gateway 192.168.0.x
```

Reboot 
then you'll find a brwlan interface between wire and wired, let's check your bridge status with brctl shows.

So your eth0 will be part of your wifi network using brwlan.
Of course you can bridge also eth2 and eth3
I hope it helps!
Regards.

Comment: This isn't quite a [link-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231), but it's close. If you've done this yourself, please try to summarize the steps here.

Comment: Ok I'll give you another answer, it's not complicated

Comment: Just edit this one.

Comment: Dear Tom It's good policy to say thanks sometimes or vote for answer.

Comment: I'll leave the voting to the person who asked the question. I have no idea whether your revised answer is good, I was just reviewing. Thanks for revising.